# On the variance of powers of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of nonnegative random variables, and let $p>1$ such that ${\rm Var\,} X_n^p\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Then the variance of each $X_n$ is finite, and it seems intuitively clear that it should tend to zero as well, but I guess I just can't find an easy proof of this fact. In short, the question is
$$
{\rm Var\,} X_n^p\to 0 \implies {\rm Var\,} X_n\to 0\,? \quad (p>1)
$$